# Gulp running more tasks than specified

Tags: gulp

I've got a gulpfile set up with both a series of tasks to bundle an Angular2 app using systemjs as well as with webpack. Unfortunately, I'm seeing that if I run one of them in my Powershell prompt (e.g. "gulp webpack" or "gulp systemjs" without the quotes), it will actually run through more of the tasks than specified in my desired task.

I won't list all the tasks I've got within this for brevity, but they all follow the standard approach, as in the following sample:

```
gulp.task("angular",
    () => {
        var angularDirs = "./Scripts/MyApp/src/**/*.{html,css}";

        return gulp.src(angularDirs)
            .pipe(copy(config.wwwroot, { prefix: 1 }))
            .pipe(gulp.dest(config.wwwroot));
    });
```

For example, here's what I've got for my webpack task:

```
gulp.task("webpack", runSequence(["cleanRoot", "cleanBuild"],
    ["ts:webpack", "restore", "less", "angular", "webpackHtml", "javascript:webpack"]));
```

...and here's what I've got in the systemjs task:

```
gulp.task("systemjs", runSequence(["cleanRoot", "cleanBuild"], "embedTemplates",
    "ts:systemjs", ["less", "restore", "angular"], "cleanWrongIndex"));
```

So, there's some overlap in there, but that's intended. However, if I run "gulp systemjs", I would expect that it'll only actually run "cleanRoot" and "cleanBuild" together, then "embedTemplates", then "ts:systemjs", the "less", "restore" and "angular" tasks and finally "cleanWrongIndex" and none of the other tasks in the file. However...

```
PS C:\Code\MyApp> gulp systemjs
[22:56:59] Using gulpfile
[22:56:59] Starting 'systemjs'...
[22:56:59] Finished 'systemjs' after 128 μs
[22:57:00] Finished 'cleanBuild' after 1.12 s
[22:57:01] Starting 'embedTemplates'...
**[22:57:01] Starting 'ts:webpack'...**
[22:57:01] Starting 'restore'...
[22:57:01] Starting 'less'...
[22:57:01] Starting 'angular'...
**[22:57:01] Starting 'webpackHtml'...**
**[22:57:01] Finished 'webpackHtml' after 705 μs**
**[22:57:01] Starting 'javascript:webpack'...**
**[22:57:01] Finished 'javascript:webpack' after 1.5 ms**
[22:57:01] Finished 'cleanRoot' after 1.9 s
[22:57:01] Finished 'restore' after 68 ms
[22:57:06] Finished 'less' after 5.65 s
[22:57:07] Finished 'angular' after 6.26 s
**[22:57:13] Finished 'ts:webpack' after 12 s**
**[22:57:14] Starting 'ts:systemjs'...**
[22:57:14] Finished 'embedTemplates' after 13 s
[22:57:20] Starting 'less'....
[22:57:20] Starting 'restore'...
[22:57:20] Starting 'angular'...
**[22:57:20] Finished 'ts:systemjs' after 5.64 s**
[22:57:20] Finished 'restore' after 161 ms
[22:57:23] Finished 'less' after 3.32 s
[22:57:23] Finished 'angular' after 3.79 s
[22:57:38] Starting 'restore'...
[22:57:38] Starting 'cleanWrongIndex'...
[22:57:38] Finished 'restore' after 25 μs
[22:57:38] Finished 'cleanWrongIndex' after 4.97 ms
PS C:\Code\MyApp>
```

I differentiated the tasks in the above that shouldn't be there since they're in the webpack task and not specified in this one.

Why are tasks showing up that I didn't specify? Is there any way to force gulp to only run the tasks I specify?

Thanks!

Comment: if one of those in systemjs has sub dependencies on webpack, it will run it.

Comment: No dependencies on any of the tasks (just to avoid doing that) and no overlap in the tasks except as named above.